# How to draw picture of a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

I have OD matrix and updated frequently and want to show over the video frame:

ie:

```
import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from tabulate import tabulate
   
fr_To = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['from', 'to'])

fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxT1' , 'Csv0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxT1' , 'Csv0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxT1' , 'Csv0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxT1' , 'Csv0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxT1' , 'Csv0']

fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CSR1' , 'CPT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CSR1' , 'CPT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CSR1' , 'CPT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CSR1' , 'CPT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CSR1' , 'CPT0']

fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']
fr_To.loc[len(fr_To.index)] = ['CxR1' , 'CsT0']

OD = fr_To.pivot_table(values='from', index="to", columns='from',            fill_value=0, aggfunc=len)
```

how I can add this OD table like attached image?

[image]

Comment: so you want to _draw_ it? ok, then _draw_ it, into a numpy array. not an opencv issue.

Comment: Am not sure the "pandas" tag is appropriate here, since the issue appears to be rendering / drawing rather than the use of a DataFrame. Assuming that's the case, you can try the Python Turtle library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html or look for toolkits at https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/7julu/anyone_know_a_good_2d_drawing_library_for_python/ and https://www.slant.co/topics/63/~best-drawing-libraries-for-python OP should probably say what library they want for video / picture edits. Please confirm & retag.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I mean how I can show pandas table over image realtime ? Is there any convenient way to do this?